# Face recognition and aging faces in c++

Tags: c++, image-processing

Hello I'm looking for some good library (opensource) that allows me to do face recognition and to easily aging faces.

Take a look for example at: http://www.in20years.com/

I need some library cross platform (not just for windows), and I would integrate that code into some iPhone Applications.

Any Suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean opensource, or do you really mean free? Not all opensource is free

Comment: @gnibbler: I mean free sorry for being unprecise.
@Jack: not so easily :-) but something that provide me some instruments to apply such an algorithm. To be honest I'm also looking for some "aging" algorithm.

Comment: I think your best choice is to ask Luxand (the algorithm behind in20years.com) if they have a iPhone-version of their library and buy that. Otherwise, you could download their demo, try to figure out how it works, maybe read some research papers about face recognition, and prepare yourself for a few years of development time to write it yourself...

Comment: @kerby82 i am also looking for the same , can you give me any reference or did you find anything?

Answer (score 3):

A basic image processing and computer vision library is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). This is the first thing to look into, but sincerely - don't expect to have all what you need already implemented there.

Comment: I know OpenCV, however it's not so easy to have aging effects, while face detection is sufficient easy.

Comment: Of course it's not easy and it's not meant to be.

Answer (score -1):

There are some facial recognition API providers. Face++ is the only one who supply all free online APIs and SDKs. It can do facial detection with up to 83 key points, and give the race, age, gender, smiling messages and so on. Maybe you can try its local iOS facial detector for your iPhone Apps.

Here's the webpage: [www.faceplusplus.com](http://www.faceplusplus.com)